# Group array by key and create an array of the related keys in each iteration

Tags: javascript

Given an array of object

```
const data = [ 
  { id: 1,
    documentation_id: 4,
    document_id: 'nil',
    category_id: 1,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z" },
  { id: 11,
    documentation_id: 10,
    document_id: 'nil',
    category_id: 1,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z" },
  { id: 2,
    documentation_id: 5,
    document_id: '1',
    category_id: 2,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z" },
  { id: 100,
    documentation_id: 15,
    document_id: '10',
    category_id: 2,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z" },
  { id: 3,
    documentation_id: 5,
    document_id: '3',
    category_id: 3,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z" },
  { id: 4,
    documentation_id: 6,
    document_id: '1',
    category_id: 4,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z" },
  { id: 5,
    documentation_id: 6,
    document_id: '3',
    category_id: 5,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z" },
  { id: 6,
    documentation_id: 6,
    document_id: '5',
    category_id: 1,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z" 
  },
  { id: 7,
    documentation_id: 7,
    document_id: '1',
    category_id: 6,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"}]
```

I want to be able to group by category_id such that result looks like this

```
const data = [{
    category_id: 1,
    documentation: [{
        document_id: "nil",
        documentation_id: 4
    }, {
        document_id: "nil",
        documentation_id: 10
    }, {
        document_id: "5",
        documentation_id: 6
    }]
}, {
    category_id: 2,
    documentation: [{
        document_id: "1",
        documentation_id: 5
    }, {
        document_id: "10",
        documentation_id: 15
    }]
}, {
    category_id: 3,
    documentation: [{
        document_id: "3",
        documentation_id: 5
    }]
}, {
    category_id: 4,
    documentation: [{
        document_id: "1",
        documentation_id: 6
    }]
}, {
    category_id: 5,
    documentation: [{
        document_id: "3",
        documentation_id: 6
    }]
}, {
    category_id: 6,
    documentation: [{
        document_id: "1",
        documentation_id: 7
    }]
}]
```

if the category exists more than once, create a documentation array and push the documentation in that category into the array. If the category exists once then push the only documentation for that category into the array.

This is the inefficient solution I came up with. I want to optimize the solution

```
function groupDocumentationByCategory(data) {
    const result = [];
    const formattedArray = data.slice(0);
    const seen = [];
    for (let k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
        if (seen.indexOf(data[k].category_id) < 0) {
            seen.push(data[k].category_id);
            formattedArray[k].documentation = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < formattedArray.length; j++) {
                if (data[k].category_id === data[j].category_id) {
                    formattedArray[k].documentation.push({
                        document_id: formattedArray[j].document_id,
                        documentation_id: formattedArray[j].documentation_id,
                    });
                    delete data[k].documentation_id;
                    delete data[k].document_id;
                    delete data[k].created_at;
                    delete data[k].updated_at;
                }
            }
            result.push(data[k]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the array and construct an object indexed by `category_id`. The first time an `category_id` is found, create the `id` and `category_id` properties, and initialize the `documentation` property to the empty array. Then push to that array. At the end, take the object's values:

```js
const data=[{id:1,documentation_id:4,document_id:"nil",category_id:1,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"},{id:11,documentation_id:10,document_id:"nil",category_id:1,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"},{id:2,documentation_id:5,document_id:"1",category_id:2,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"},{id:100,documentation_id:15,document_id:"10",category_id:2,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"},{id:3,documentation_id:5,document_id:"3",category_id:3,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"},{id:4,documentation_id:6,document_id:"1",category_id:4,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"},{id:5,documentation_id:6,document_id:"3",category_id:5,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"},{id:6,documentation_id:6,document_id:"5",category_id:1,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"},{id:7,documentation_id:7,document_id:"1",category_id:6,created_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",updated_at:"2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"}];

const dataByCategory = {};
for (const { id, category_id, document_id, documentation_id } of data) {
  if (!dataByCategory[category_id]) {
    dataByCategory[category_id] = {
      id,
      category_id,
      documentation: []
    };
  }
  dataByCategory[category_id].documentation.push({ document_id, documentation_id });
}

console.log(Object.values(dataByCategory));
```

Comment: What is the run time of this algorithm if I may ask. 0(n) ?

Comment: Yes, it's just a plain iteration through all elements of the original array, `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` combined with some `Array.prototype.map` to achieve the result.

Maybe it can help.

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    documentation_id: 4,
    document_id: "nil",
    category_id: 1,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    documentation_id: 10,
    document_id: "nil",
    category_id: 1,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    documentation_id: 5,
    document_id: "1",
    category_id: 2,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 100,
    documentation_id: 15,
    document_id: "10",
    category_id: 2,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    documentation_id: 5,
    document_id: "3",
    category_id: 3,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    documentation_id: 6,
    document_id: "1",
    category_id: 4,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    documentation_id: 6,
    document_id: "3",
    category_id: 5,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    documentation_id: 6,
    document_id: "5",
    category_id: 1,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    documentation_id: 7,
    document_id: "1",
    category_id: 6,
    created_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z",
    updated_at: "2020-03-29T11:06:44.000Z"
  }
];

data = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (acc[val.category_id]) {
    acc[val.category_id].push(val);
  } else {
    acc[val.category_id] = [val];
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

data = Object.values(data)
  .map(val => {
    delete val.created_at;
    delete val.updated_at;
    return val;
  })
  .reduce((acc, val) => {
    let documentation = val.map(v => ({
      document_id: v.document_id,
      documentation_id: v.documentation_id
    }));
    acc.push({
      category_id: val[0].category_id,
      documentation
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(data);
```